# Invoking custom action through google assistant

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

I have an android app(UserApp) that contains a list view with a list of usernames. Clicking on any list item takes us to the user detail page where it shows the Name, Address, Phone number, picture and so on. I want to perform an interaction on my app through assistant, like I say Ok Google " open Nagendra on UserApp", it should take me to the User Detail page of Nagendra. How can I achieve this? I found very little documentation on developer.android.com through which I couldn't get my job done. I just need the template of API calls to invoke custom interaction in android app using google assistant.

Comment: This type of interaction is infeasible with the current developer platform.

Comment: But if we say call <Nagendra> on Google Assistant, it will automatically open the dialler app and dial the number to Nagendra. In the same way, there should be an api available to invoking actions on other apps.

Comment: There aren't hooks exposed to third-party developers in the same way.

Comment: At least for Android [App Actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/) are going to be what you want. But only for a select few intents.Right now they are not available though (actually this site hasn't change in roughly six months - so they are in no rush to make this available).

Comment: There's an action - actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE - that seems to be related to what you're describing but there's barely any documentation on this, it's a shame because I'm also looking for something similar and still no luck